# Loading SSL library in Python

Tags: python, django, ssl

I would like to import OpenSSL library in order to use EVP_MD object in Python. I used sslsnoop by this reason. However, an error occured when I tried to import library in python code.

```
from sslsnoop import ctypes_openssl
```

Here is the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting HAYSTACK_ID_FIELD, but
settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

What Should I do?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Just bike shedding: I think [M2Crypto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2Crypto) is usually used for OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EVP_MD and EVP_CIPHER libraries what I was looking for.I solved the problem by these links:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html#

https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html#

https://seattle.poly.edu/svn/seattle/trunk/tuf/evpy/evp.py